# jQuery or JavaScript compare two arrays one contains an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

MyIds has just two Id numbers 1 and 2

```
var MyIds = [1,2]
```

but MyObject has three Id numbers 1, 2 and 3 (In reality this has about 500 Id's)

```
var MyObject = [{id:1,size:21,length:31},{id:2,size:22,length:32},{id:3,size:23,length:33}]
```

and I want to make a new variable that looks like this, I need some magic code that will compare the two variables and only return the details of the objects where the Is's match

```
var Result = [{id:1,size:21,length:31},{id:2,size:22,length:32}]
```

I'm happy to use jQuery if it help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var Result = MyObject.filter(function(item){
  return MyIds.indexOf(item.id) >-1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily solved with underscore or lodash with something like:

```
Result = _.filter(MyObject, function (item) {
    return _.indexOf(item.id, MyIds) !== -1;
});
```

I admit, this is a lazy answer. There is probably a way to make it without adding a news library. But lodash is so cool :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without jQuery:

```
var MyIds = [1,2];
var MyObject = [{id:1,size:21,length:31},{id:2,size:22,length:32},{id:3,size:23,length:33}];

var Result = [];

MyObject.forEach(function(element) {
    MyIds.forEach(function(id){
      if(element.id == id)
        Result.push(element);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A more diverse sollution without using any library:

```
  function find(propName, filters, collection){
    var temp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < filters.length; j++){
            if(collection[i][propName] === filters[j]){
                temp.push(collection[i]);   
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
```